# Passing data-id doesn't work in JS function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I have a problem in my JS script--when I want to pass the id of a notification in data-id, it doesn't work.

my JS function:

```js
function getNotification() {
            var res = "<ul class='list-group'>";
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Notification/getNotification",
                method: "GET",
                success: function (result) {
    
                    if (result.count != 0) {
                        $("#notificationCount").html(result.count);
                        $("#notificationCount").show('slow');
                    } else {
                        $("#notificationCount").html();
                        $("#notificationCount").hide('slow');
                        $("#notificationCount").popover('hide');
                    }
    
                    var notifications = result.userNotification;
                    notifications.forEach(element => {
    
                        res = res + "<li class='list-group-item notification-text' data-id='" + element.notification.id + "'>" + element.notification.text + "</li>";
    
                    });
    
                    res = res + "</ul>";
    
                    $("#notification-content").html(res);
    
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
```

and when I run and I inspect the page this is the result without data-id:

```html
<li class="list-group-item notification-text">new event "event1"</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,when I use the following code,I can get `data-id`:

View:

```
<div id="notification-content"></div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var res = "<ul class='list-group'>";
        $.ajax({
            url: "/FileManager/getNotification",
            method: "GET",
            success: function (result) {


                var notifications = result.userNotification;
                notifications.forEach(element => {
                   
                    res = res + "<li class='list-group-item notification-text' data-id='" + element.notification.id + "'>" + element.notification.text + "</li>";

                });

                res = res + "</ul>";

                $("#notification-content").html(res);

                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
      
    })
</script>
```

Models:

```
public class FileManagerViewModel {
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
public class UNotification
    {
        public Notification Notification { get; set; }

    }
    public class Notification
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult getNotification() {
            List<UNotification> l = new List<UNotification> { new UNotification {Notification= new Notification { Id = 1, Text = "new event \"event1\"" } }, new UNotification { Notification = new Notification { Id = 2, Text = "sssssssdddds" } } };
            return Json(new { userNotification =l});
        }
```

result:
[image]
If it still cannot work for you,you can also try the following code:

```
<div id="notification-content"></div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var r = $("<ul/>").addClass("list-group");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/FileManager/getNotification",
            method: "GET",
            success: function (result) {


                var notifications = result.userNotification;
                notifications.forEach(element => {
                    var li = $("<li/>").addClass("list-group-item notification-text").attr("data-id", element.notification.id).text(element.notification.text).appendTo(r);


                });

                $("#notification-content").html(r);

                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
      
    })
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment . but still won't work

Comment: i think its js problem , i don't know what to import to make data-id work perfectly ..

Comment: If you add `<li class="list-group-item notification-text" data-id="1">new event "event1"</li>` directly to html,can you get `data-id`?And what the value of element.notification.id?

Comment: no i try it but still the data attributes won't work .. and element.notification.id work perfectly i test it with id and it works good but only data-* won't work in the popover

Comment: What is the version of your jquery?And can you show your js loaded?

Comment: i use many version of jquery now its 3.5.1 ... ... about my js loaded actually im still begginer so i cant understand what u mean by it

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
i use all of thos script in the same layout ! is that good!! im still begginer so i dont know how to work with it